# Importing CSV where separator is contained in string

Tags: r, csv, import, read.table

I have a CSV with 3 columns, separated by commas (",")

Unfortunately, there are a few lines like this:

```
6, 2015-04-14, "\"this is, a test\""
```

Which `read.table` interprets to be 4 columns instead of 3, because of the additional "," within the quotes.

How do I get around this?

Comment: `read.csv` works fine for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within double quotes `read.csv` regards two consecutive double quotes as one double quote of content (not a delimiter) so read in the lines verbatim using `readLines`, use `chartr` to replace each backslash with a double quote and then use `read.csv` to read the resulting lines:

```
read.csv(text = chartr('\\', '"', readLines("myfile.csv")))
```

Alternately it may be that we do not really want the inner double quotes at all in which case just replace `\"` with an empty string:

```
read.csv(text = gsub('\\"', '', readLines("myfile.csv"), fixed = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 2):

This may suffice:

```
test  <- read.table("test.csv",sep = ",",quote = '\\')
test
V1          V2                   V3
1  6  2015-04-14  ""this is, a test""
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to change the delimiter in your csv file to something that doesn't collide with your "\w,\w" stuff in your strings. I do this where I need to in a pre-process step to get the data ready for import. You can easily re-export the data file from where you got it with tab delimiters, for example. Then, in R, you will read it in with

```
read.csv2("data/myfile.tsv", header=TRUE, sep = "\t")
```